# Selecting distinct rows based on column

Tags: sql

A particular query of mine results data this way.

```
 Id    Size  
 123     1
 123     1
 123     2
 123     2
 134     1
 134     1
 134     2
```

I want the results get me the count eliminating the duplicate size like

```
 Id    Size  
 123     1
 123     2
 134     1
 134     2
```

Above was result of joining two tables. Problem is I cant use distinct in this case.

Here is how tables are

```
Table1:
   Id Created ... .. .. ..
   123 date1 ....
   134 date2 ....

Table2:     
 Id    Size  
 123     1
 123     2
 134     1
 134     2
```

I have my query that select from Table1 based on CreatedDate, its like this

```
 select count(*)
 from table1

 join table2
 on table1.id = table2.id

 where table1.creates between '' and ''.
```

How do you get the distinct sizes.

If I use select count(distinct table2.size), it only returns 1 and 2 for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Size
    FROM table1
```

This should give you a list of distinct Id and Size combinations.

Comment: Yes it should work. To be more precisely 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Size FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.Id = table2.Id
    AND table1.creates between '' and ''

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(distinct table1.id, table2.size)
 from table1

 join table2
 on table1.id = table2.id

 where table1.creates between '' and ''
```

- see it working live in an **<kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54045/5/0)</kbd>**

Sometimes the solution is so obvious... :)

UPDATE: another way

```
select count(*) from (
     select distinct table1.id, table2.size
     from table1

     join table2
     on table1.id = table2.id

     where table1.creates between '' and ''
) sq
```

Comment: count will cause it to only display count, not the rows themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont see count() as you mentioned above working. Incorrect syntax near ','. Is there a different syntax I should use?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Well, in the question it's asked about the count, not the rows.

Comment: @user3285499 Which RDBMS are you using? My solution is for MySQL as can be seen in the sqlfiddle. I've updated my question with a solution working in every RDBMS.